# How to launch selenium through command line

Tags: java, selenium, command-line-interface

I want to launch the selenium code on my mac.

With IntelliJ, I can launch each tests through the interface (thanks to the green button on the left).

I need now to launch selenium through cli, how to I do ?

My folder structure : **/project/src/test/java/project_test/Tests.java**

(I'm trying this right now : https://docs.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/, but as I have my driver inside my function I don't know if it will work, I'll let you know)

One example of my test :

```
 public void TestA() throws InterruptedException, MessagingException {
    String nameError = "TestA";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", locateDriver);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.navigate().to(url + "route");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".primary > a[href=\""+url+"connexion/connexion/index/\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-client")).sendKeys("40003099");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-cp")).sendKeys("281101");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement strvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"maincontent\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String expected = "some text";
    String actual = strvalue.getText();
    System.out.println(actual);
    if(expected.equals(actual)){
        System.out.println("Ok");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not ok");
        sendMail(nameError);
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: build an executable jar file and run that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run java file using external jar ? if yes, maybe this can help.

First, go to your directory :

```
cd project

MacBook-Pro: project$
```

Second, run this command :

```
java -cp .:yourFullPathExternalJar\*: src.test.java.project_test.Tests
```

Hope this helps